# how to sync data from local code to heroku git

Tags: node.js, git, heroku

I build some website using nodeJS that host on heroku. I am using the heroku CLI git. When i want to upload the files i am using the git add . after that  git commit -am "some text" and git push heroku master.
The client is update his site and upload new images and content, and when i make some changes in the code and git it again all the work he is done is deleted from server (not from DB).

Add the images folder to the .gitignore file

How can i sync files and code with my local version before i push new version to the heroku server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you do "git add ." you are telling git to overwrite all your files from git with code on you local. 
if you have made changes in only specific files You should always add only those files when doing git add .

you can follow this steps.

1. **git status** -> this will show you list of files which are changes and umerged. get hold of file which you changed and want to add in git 
   Suppose its abc.html (copy full path of file shown in git status)
2. **git add abc.html**
3. **git commit -m "some message"**
4. (optional) **git pull remote_branch current_branch** (this will pull latest code of remote branch to your local). Sometimes you may get conflicts so go ahead open that file and resolve conflicts.
   If you are alone working on branch you may not get any conflicts
5. **git push current_branch remote_branch**